# How can I display date? I only want the date in real time

Tags: javascript, date

How can I display date? I only want the date in real time.

```
const currentDate = document.getElementById('#date');

function today() {

    let dt = new Date();

    let dd = dt.getDate();

    let dm = dt.getMonth();

    let dfy = dt.getFullYear();

    if(dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }

    if(dm < 10) {
        dm = '0' + dm;
    }

    currentDate.innerHTML = dd + "-" + dm + "-" + dfy; 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent called the function today().

```js
let dt = new Date();

let dd = dt.getDate();

let dm = (dt.getMonth() + 1);

let dfy = dt.getFullYear();

if(dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
}

if(dm < 10) {
    dm = '0' + dm;
}

document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = dd + "-" + dm + "-" + dfy;
```

```html
<p id="date"> </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need # in the getElementById

Comment: I removed but still does not work. Is there any other way to display real time date?